# Ruby Command Line to simulate enter key for SVN propedit svn:ignore

Tags: ruby, shell, svn, command-line, automation

I have an automation program I'm working on that's written in Ruby. During the process of the program I need to have an SVN repo ignore 2 or more files. This process has no user input, so using commands like `svn propedit svn:ignore .` is not a possibility as it will open a text editor to request the files.

Typically how I would handle this directly from the shell would be to utilize `propset svn:ignore` and hit `[ENTER]` in-between file names to continue the statement:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "filename1
> filename2" .
```

I tried simulating this using the following Ruby statement:

```
system("svn propedit svn:ignore 'filename1")
system("filename2' .")
```

But upon execution I receive the following error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I've also tried creating a `dir-props` file in the `.svn` directory but couldn't get the changes to register with the repository. I verified this with `svn proplist -v -R`. Even if this did work I can't guarantee it'd be successful in all the possible scenarios I have with this program.

I've been at this for quite awhile now and have run out of ideas. I tried searching for a Ruby command that would allow me to simulate a key press between the two lines of the `propedit svn:ignore` command and was unsuccessful.

Anyone have a solution for how I should handle this? Its vital for my program to run correctly. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a work around that seems to do the trick by creating an ignore file and feeding that to `svn propset`. Not sure if there is a better solution to this but this is at least meeting my needs:

```
    File.open("ignore.txt", "wb") { |f| f.write("filename1\nfilename2\n") }
    system("svn propset svn:ignore -F ignore.txt .")
    File.delete("ignore.txt")
```